# How to improve font rendering in Firefox

Tags: firefox, fonts

I'm Firefox 64 developer edition under Linux. Fonts look uglier than Chrome. What can I do to improve them?
[Firefox vs Chrome fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxlsf.png)

What I've tried so far, without any improvement:

- disabled hardware acceleration
- gfx.canvas.azure.backends =
  direct2d1.1,cairo,skia
- gfx.content.azure.backends =
  direct2d1.1,cairo,skia

Comment: Try the fixes from [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/4ggqzo/psa_fix_firefox_fonts_on_windows/). Note well the old values before.

Comment: Thanks, none of the setting provided in the linked post are available in my ff. I'm using version 64.0b7